Resque Remove Job Via Unique Key Or Partial Arguments
I have an issue where I want to replace a job if a new job with the same unique key (but different arguments) is queued up. Ideally checking both 1 argument and the unique key.
The reason for this is that these jobs are run on updates, so if update 1 fails and it is retried later, it shouldn't override update 2.
Resque job deletion seems to require all arguments though, which is a bit of a problem. Is there a way to delete a job with only partial arguments? Is there any other way to solve this issue?
